# Correct regex for traceroute output

Tags: regex, linux, pcre

Below sample output is dumped by traceroute and I want to use pcre expression to exract some data.

```
host-1 (1.1.1.1)  10.111 ms  20.222 ms host-2 (2.2.2.2)  21.716 ms
host-3 (2.2.2.2)  10.111 ms  31.716 ms  21.716 ms
```

I need to have in one line:

```
 - domain : host-1
 - ip : 1.1.1.1
 - t1 : 10.111
 - t2 : 20.222

 - domain eg: host-2
 - ip : 2.2.2.2
 - t1 : 21.716

 - domain eg: host-3
 - t1 : 10.111
 - t2 : 31.716
 - t3 : 21.716
```

I used this regex with pcretest `/(?:(?:([\w\-\.]+)\s\(([\d+\.]+)\))(?:\s+(\d+\.\d+)\sms){1,3})*/g`

But I can only have last response time after domain and IP, in example for the line `host-3 (2.2.2.2)  10.111 ms  31.716 ms  21.716 ms` only 21.716 is returned.

What can be the correct regex?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of work is best done with AWK in unix. If you want to split the string on Tab you can pipe it into awk and are able to access individual elements of the input by using $1, $2... and so on. Some example of awk syntax is:

"some_command" | awk '{print $2}'

and if you want to read further your best bet would be this guide [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)